# re.sub - multi value and multi lines substitution

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Let's say we have file `in.conf` with text:

```
line1 = %var1%
line2 = %var2%
line3 = %var3%
```

And we have script, which must replace all `%var(s)%` in `in.conf` and generate new file - `out.conf`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

infile = 'in.conf'
outfile = 'out.conf'

change_vars_list = ('%var1%', '%var2%', '%var3%')
change_values_list = ('newvalue1', 'newvalue2', 'newvalue3')

with open(infile, 'r') as inconf:
    lines = inconf.read()

    print('\nRaw lines:\n\n%s' % lines)
    print('\nVars to change:')
    print(change_vars_list)

    outdata = re.sub(r'%var1%', 'NEWVALUE', lines)
    print('\nNew data:\n\n%s\n' % outdata)

with open(outfile, 'w') as outconf:
    outconf.write(outdata)
```

While `re.sub` called for only `%var1%` - this works excellent:

```
$ ./replace.py

Raw lines:

line1 = %var1%
line2 = %var2%
line3 = %var3%


Vars to change:
('%var1%', '%var2%', '%var3%')

New data:

line1 = NEWVALUE
line2 = %var2%
line3 = %var3%

$ cat out.conf
line1 = NEWVALUE
line2 = %var2%
line3 = %var3%
```

But - how can I realize, that same script can replace all `%var(s)%` with given values from `change_values_list` and save them to new file `out.conf`?

So - `out.conf` must looks like:

```
line1 = newvalue1
line2 = newvalue2
line3 = newvalue3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing your initial code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re

infile = 'in.conf'
outfile = 'out.conf'

change_vars_list = (r'%var1%', r'%var2%', r'%var3%')
change_values_list = ('newvalue1', 'newvalue2', 'newvalue3')

with open(infile, 'r') as inconf:
    lines = inconf.read()

    print('\nRaw lines:\n\n%s' % lines)
    print('\nVars to change:')
    print(change_vars_list)

    outdata = lines
    for var, value in zip(change_vars_list, change_values_list):
        outdata = re.sub(var, value, outdata)

    print('\nNew data:\n\n%s\n' % outdata)

with open(outfile, 'w') as outconf:
    outconf.write(outdata)
```

Or, if it's always simple substitution, you can just use the `replace` string function:

```
for var, value in zip(change_vars_list, change_values_list):
    outdata = outdata.replace(var, value)
```

Comment: Thanks. first part (`outdata = re.sub(var, value, outdata)`) works. I faced wi th one more issue - there is lines, which not includes `change_vars_list`, but with your tips - all works.

Comment: Are you saying you have extra values to change? Are the vars & values regular (like in your example, `%var1` -> `newvalue1`; `%var2` -> `newvalue2`, each var & value set only changes by a number)? Or are they arbitrary?

Answer (score 0):

Don't sure this is best solution - but it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

infile = 'in.conf'
outfile = 'out.conf'

change_vars_list = ('%var1%', '%var2%', '%var3%')
change_values_list = ('newvalue1', 'newvalue2', 'newvalue3')

with open(outfile, 'r+') as outconf:
    with open (infile, 'r') as inconf:
            for line, var, value in zip(inconf, change_vars_list, change_values_list):
                print('Var %s value %s' % (var, value))
                outconf.write(line.replace(var, value))

$ ./replace.py
Var %var1% value newvalue1
Var %var2% value newvalue2
Var %var3% value newvalue3

$ cat out.conf
line1 = newvalue1
line2 = newvalue2
line3 = newvalue3
```

But still hope for some other idea...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
outdata = re.sub(r'%var[0-9]%', 'NEWVALUE', lines)
```

The first parameter of `re.sub` is a regular expression pattern. You'll find a useful cheatsheet and can test your patterns [here](http://pythex.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Just solving the core issue, as you're handling the files just fine already:

```
template = 'line1 = %var1%\nline2 = %var2%\nline3 = %var3%'
change_vars_list = ('%var1%', '%var2%', '%var3%')
change_values_list = ('newvalue1', 'newvalue2', 'newvalue3')
changes = dict(zip(change_vars_list, change_values_list))
import re
print(re.sub('|'.join(changes),
             lambda match: changes[match.group()],
             template))
```

Prints:

```
line1 = newvalue1
line2 = newvalue2
line3 = newvalue3
```

Unless you have a good reason to specify `change_vars_list` and `change_values_list` separately, I'd write them like this:

```
template = 'line1 = %var1%\nline2 = %var2%\nline3 = %var3%'
changes = {'%var1%': 'newvalue1',
           '%var2%': 'newvalue2',
           '%var3%': 'newvalue3'}
import re
print(re.sub('|'.join(changes),
             lambda match: changes[match.group()],
             template))
```

Alternatively, if you don't insist on using regular expressions:

```
template = 'line1 = %var1%\nline2 = %var2%\nline3 = %var3%'
change_vars_list = ('%var1%', '%var2%', '%var3%')
change_values_list = ('newvalue1', 'newvalue2', 'newvalue3')
for var, value in zip(change_vars_list, change_values_list):
    template = template.replace(var, value)
print(template)
```

Or shorter again:

```
template = 'line1 = %var1%\nline2 = %var2%\nline3 = %var3%'
changes = (('%var1%', 'newvalue1'),
           ('%var2%', 'newvalue2'),
           ('%var3%', 'newvalue3'))
for var, value in changes:
    template = template.replace(var, value)
print(template)
```